# Ionic 2 serve call npm script after every build

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

In my ionic 2 app, I normally develop by running `ionic serve`. I have an npm task that I would like to run after each build finishes. I've done some research but can't seem to find an answer.

How do I run an npm scripts task(i.e. `npm run my-custom-task`) after every build from `ionic serve`?

Here is the desired workflow:

1. Run `ionic serve` command
2. The build finishes
3. my npm script is run
4. I change a file
5. ionic's watcher restarts the build
6. the build finishes
7. my npm script is run
8. repeat 3-6 every time a file changes

Comment: maybe this will help. https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/app-scripts/

Comment: just to make it clear, you want some scripts to run after the build and just before web-server fires up?

Comment: @n00b, not exactly. I have updated my question with a little more information.

Comment: I thought the --copy that allows you to have custom copy scripts should be able to do this. but no luck! https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts